# doctrine create query - parameter and value

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

i have table in mysql:

```
id | num1 | num2| num 3| num3| num5|
1  | 6    | 3   | 4    | 2   | 1   |
```

$num = num2; $val = 2; $id = 2;

if i use

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('TABLE')
->set($num, '?', $val)
->where('id = ?', $id)
->execute();
```

work OK, but i use:

```
            $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->from('TABLE')
          ->where('id = ?', $id)
          ->andWhere($num ,' ?', $val)
          ->execute();
```

doesn't work. i have: 500 Internal Server Error

Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the value for $num come from? It looks very suspicious and I'd be cautious on how you proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->andWhere($num ,' ?', $val)` [is invalid](https://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#where-clause).

your should try

```
->andWhere('num'.$num.' = ?', $val)
```